# Release writing permission in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, uac, .net

I am trying to release a C++ .Net application and am getting very frustrated with Windows UAC. I have not much experience with this as have always been writing for XP.

The program needs to update some properties that are stored in two XML files and every time it tries it gets access denied if it is not running with an Administrator account.
I have followed the recommendations from Microsoft and am writing all the files that need to be modified to the CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA folder. The installer has an action that creates the [Organization}[Program] structure within the later and adds the security group Every One with full control privilege because by default, that directory is read only.
I have verified that the cretated directory [Organization}[Program] does actually contains the group and the privilege assigned after installing.
Also, the application has a manifest with a requestedExecutionLevel, which I have tried asinvoker and Highestavailable.

The application is still not being capable of writing to the directory unless the user is not logged as Administrator...

The machines are in a domain controled by a server 2003 but the clients are a mix of XP, vista and 7.

Please, could someone with more experience in this than I enlight me?
Should I use some other folder? The problem is that Different users might log into the computer and those settings are common, therefore the obvious User folder is not an option.

I cannot either add the user to the security of the folders with the installer because I don't know which user from the domain will use the program and I cannot do it from the program when starting because if the user does not have adminstrator rights the program will just be blocked.

Please, any advise or indication about what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/e87516e7-8983-45bc-ba9e-e32c3e748b73)  may discuss your problem. See especially

> Your application's installer needs to set ACLs on your subdirectory of CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA to allow users to access that directory as required by your application

Comment: I believe I have done it by adding to the ACL the Group Everyone with Full control assigned. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As noted above, perhaps I didn't explain myself well in the question. I am actually doing that when creating the group Everyone and giving it Full control over the subdirectory. However, I still get the access denied...

Comment: This does not answer the question, please. That has been done as was explained in the question originally.

Comment: Sorry to hear that this doesn't fix your problem. However I don't have any other suggestions.